# How to check extension of file using Platform::String?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm trying to check whether StorageFile is a zip file.
I can convert the StorageFile to it's full name including it's extension.

However there are very little helpful methods within Platform::String that I can use to check file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On StorageFile object, there is a method called FileType.
That retrieves an extension Platform::String of your StorageFile.

ex. String^ extension = storageFile->FileType;

Answer (score 0):

Given the name, I'd expect [`Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to work for you, if you're using the .NET "view" of WinRT. (I don't know if there's a direct equivalent in WinRT itself. Looking now.)